# PySpark dataframe repartition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

What happens when we do repartition on a PySpark dataframe based on the column. For example

```
dataframe.repartition('id')
```

Does this moves the data with the similar `'id'` to the same partition? How does the `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` value affect the repartition?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default value for `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` is 200, and configures the number of partitions that are used when shuffling data for joins or aggregations.

`dataframe.repartition('id')` creates 200 partitions with ID partitioned based on Hash Partitioner. Dataframe Row's with the same ID always goes to the same partition. If there is DataSkew on some ID's, you'll end up with inconsistently sized partitions.

Comment: Ideally means that all the data of a particular ID will be located on the same worker node right?